# How to use `pfctl` to define a kill switch?

Tags: firewall, pfctl

I use WireGuard, specifically `wg-quick`, to tunnel both my IPv4 and IPv6 traffic through a VPN server. However, I have noticed that my tunnel often leaks IPv6 traffic to my ISP after waking up from sleep.

The local traffic is excluded from the tunnel, if it matters.

My question is whether it is possible to create a kill switch using `pfctl` to prevent this leakage.

The equivalent `iptables` rules in Linux are:

```
PostUp  = iptables -I OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT && ip6tables -I OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT
PreDown = iptables -D OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT && ip6tables -D OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT
```